# How to connect to ActiveMQ on startup with WCF and IIS

Tags: wcf, startup, activemq-classic, appfabric

What is the best way to combine a single instance WCF service that uses ActiveMQ and runs within IIS/AppFabric?

Our Services need to support both HTTP transports and ActiveMQ (listening and sending messages). We've elected not to use MSMQ, and will use Spring.Net.NMS. The fundamental issue I have now is that ActiveMQ needs to connect to the queue(s) at startup and remain connected, but WAS is getting in the way with it's message-activation feature. If the service is not activated until a message arrives (HTTP/MSMQ, etc) then there is no trigger to have the connection to AMQ occur.

I know I can disable the recycling behavior, and I know I can do self-hosting with a Windows Service. But I want to take advantage of the monitoring and other features in AppFabric. I've already been down the route with IServiceBehavior and will use that for other nice things. But that interface is not called until a (non-AMQ) message arrives. So it won't work for this. What I was hoping for was something along the line of how ServletContextListeners work in Java, where you get both the start up and shutdown events. But it seems no such thing exists in WAS... it is driven only by messages arriving.

I've scoured every inch of web info for 3 days and the only thing I came across was to use a static class construction (C#) trick as the trigger. That's a hack, but i can live with it. It still leaves the issue of cleanly shutting down, which I can figure out later.

Anyone have a solid solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

The direct WCF support for ActiveMQ that Ladislav mentions is still being supported.  There just hasn't been an official release for the module in a while.  However, you can still get the latest version of it from the 1.5.x branch or trunk and compile it yourself.

1.5.x branch for use with Apache.NMS 1.5.0:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq/activemq-dotnet/Apache.NMS.WCF/branches/1.5.x/

Check out instructions:
http://activemq.apache.org/nms/source.html

Answer (score 1):

There was [direct WCF support for ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/nms/apachenmswcf-v110.html) but I guess it is not developed anymore. Your problem actually is the IIS / WAS (provides hosting for non-http protocols) hosting architecture. Services in WAS are always activated when message arrives - there is no global startup. The reason for this is that WAS hosting expects that there is separate process (windows service) running the listener all the time and this process has adapter which calls WAS and uses message level activation. I guess you don't have such process for ActiveMQ and because of that you will have trouble to use ActiveMQ endpoint hosted in WAS. Developing such listener can be challenging task ([example for UDP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717041.aspx)).

Creating custom listener can be probably avoided by using IIS 7.5 / AppFabric [auto start feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677260.aspx). There is also not very well documented way to [run the code when the application starts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2006/01/11/511514.aspx).